# Generate "Instances" definition programmatically to create EMR cluster in StepFunctions

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I have a case where I want to dynamically create an EMR cluster based on a user-defined configuration and execute a sequence of steps on it using AWS Step Functions.

For this, I am planning to provide the instance configuration as an input to the step functions workflow.

Based on the [StepFunctions-EMR Integration Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-emr.html), the definition is the same as that of the RunJobFlow API.

However, when I try to generate the definition by serializing an instance of JobFlowInstancesConfig to JSON and pass it to the StateMachine as an input, it throws an error saying:

```
The field 'Instances.KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps' is required but was missing
```

Here is the JSON generated post serialization:

```
{
    "instanceFleets": [
        {
            "instanceFleetType": "MAIN",
            "targetOnDemandCapacity": 1,
            "instanceTypeConfigs": [
                {
                    "instanceType": "m5.xlarge"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "instanceFleetType": "CORE",
            "targetOnDemandCapacity": 1,
            "instanceTypeConfigs": [
                {
                    "instanceType": "c5.2xlarge"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "keepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": true
}
```

I am passing this in the input, and accessing it in my StepFunctions definition in the below Task (where I expect the above definition to be replacing `$.jobFlowInstancesConfig`):

```
...
"GetCluster": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:createCluster.sync",
    "Parameters": {
        "Name.$": "$.clusterName",
        "VisibleToAllUsers": true,
        "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.30.0",
        "Applications": [
            {
                "Name": "Spark"
            }
        ],
        "ServiceRole": "EMR_DefaultRole",
        "JobFlowRole": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
        "LogUri": "s3://my-aws-logs/elasticmapreduce/",
        "Instances.$": "$.jobFlowInstancesConfig"
    }
}
...
```

My suspicion is that this is failing because StepFunctions expects the field names to start with upper case.

**Question: How do I programmatically generate the appropriate definition without having to play around with Strings for generating the JSON? Is there a straightforward way to serialize the above definition to one that will work with StepFunctions?**

Comment: Is there any particular reason on why can't you use the names with upper case? (InstanceFleets, KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps, etc)?

Comment: There's not reason I can't, it's just that I'll have to generate the entire payload string manually instead of creating an object instance and serializing it with a utility class.

Comment: same question, i need know how agree instance groups